# Deletion using gsub in R

Tags: r, gsub

I want to transform the values in a column in my dataframe (df). The values are of the type e.g. "55.867.271" where I would like to remove the "." and obtain "55867271".

I have tried the following with gsub:

```
df$column <- gsub(".","",df$column)
```

yet this results in a blank df$column. Help in solving this matter would be much appreciated.

It is to note that the column class is factor. Does the class of the column matter though?

Sincerily, ykl

Comment: A `.` in regex is a  wildcard. You need to escape it: `\\.`

Comment: Thank you so much. Where can I learn more about regex and its wildcards, etc?

Comment: You can start by reading the help in `?regex`. And there's enough regex-testers online, where you can input your text and your pattern and see how they match. Practical for debugging.

Comment: you can try `gsub(".", "", "55.867.271", fixed=TRUE)`. The point is litteraly interpreted.

Comment: fixed = TRUE seems quite useful. Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: If you don't want to have a bunch of backslashes (or to escape only the needed ones) you can use `[.]` which is sually easier to remind it's a litteral dot, same for `()` etc. as already said by @Heroka the regex doc has valuable information